# How do I make a single program not ask for admin perms for another user?

Tags: windows, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

Here's the situation: My son and I share the same computer, I have the admin account and he has a regular user account. He plays Genshin Impact and every time he wants to play he needs me to input my admin password.

Is there a way to stop that? Can I just make that single executable file have special permissions and leave everything else as is?

Comment: Good question, I'm thinking the quick answer is no, that is on the programmer/company that made the SW. I DO think someone might have a workaround, I feel like I should have this answer after 10yr in IT. You COULD use the `runas` command in a batch file but I'm not sure if you do it without explicitly putting your pswd in plaintext

Comment: If an application is designed to be elevated there isn’t anything you can do to get around that requirement

Comment: Similar older question: https://superuser.com/questions/528838/how-to-change-run-permission-for-ordinary-user-for-windows-vista?rq=1

Comment: The makers "claim" that the problem has been resolved.  I also see them blaming it on anti-cheat technology.  Who knows?  I wouldn't trust a company overseen by the CCP running free on my drive as an admin.  Perhaps run it in a VM?  Then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Ramhound since OP & we can't control this app requiring admin, I think they are wondering about a way to discretely supply the admin password for this one app so it doesn't prompt for it, but has it via the workaround we supply/advise. I say discretely as I imagine he wouldn't want the son to have it otherwise the problem would already be resolved

Comment: I WAS thinking maybe this could be done with `runas /savecred`, but this may open your PC up to security flaws: https://superuser.com/questions/581548/runas-savecred-ask-for-password-if-another-user-runs-the-same-batch-file
@OP I can appreciate the desire/question, it seems the common-sense answer is the software maker is doing this to you

Comment: SUGGESTION:  Try creating a .bat file or .ps1 PowerShell script with `runas /user:"username" /savecred "path-to-exe"`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! I tried `runas` but I was prompted by an error saying that the command needed elevation. :(

Comment: As you have noted, running the command requires elevation so my posted answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

> every time he wants to play he needs me to input my admin password.

It depends on the App. If the App (say like Sync Back Pro) provides a Manifest file or like method to permit Standard Users to run the App, then you can.

If the App does not provide a feature like this (many Apps do not) then only a Administrator can start the App and you cannot do what you are suggesting.